# How can I add a new line in a Bash string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ash

The new line `\n` is not taken account in the shell strings:

```
str="aaa\nbbbb"
echo $str
```

Output:

```
aaa\nbbbb
```

Expected result:

```
aaa
bbbb
```

How can I add a new line in the string?

Comment: linuxcdeveloper: always try to use echo -e "your display part" it makes the right effect( -e : enable interpretation of backslash escapes )

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
$ echo "a\nb"
a\nb
$ echo -e "a\nb"
a
b
```

Comment: So succinct it's art.